# C++ reorder function-arguments with a template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a number of overloaded functions of 2 arguments. I would like a function-template that allows the arguments to be called in the reverse-order so that I needn't manually define `foo(B,A)` for every `foo(A,B)`:

```cpp
class Person {};
class Alice : public Person {};
class Bob : public Person {};

int foo(const Person&, const Person&)
{
  return 0x00;
}

int foo(const Bob&, const Alice&)
{
  return 0xBA;
}

int transpose(int ii)
{
  return ((ii & 0x0F) << 4) | ((ii & 0xF0) >> 4);
}

template<typename A, typename B>
int foo(const A& a, const B& b)
{
  return transpose(foo(b, a));
}

TEST(CPP, transpose)
{
  Alice aa;
  Bob bb;
  Person cc;
  EXPECT_EQ(foo(bb, aa), 0xBA); // PASS
  EXPECT_EQ(foo(aa, bb), 0xAB); // PASS
  EXPECT_EQ(foo(cc, aa), 0x00); // infinite recursion :(
}
```

This infinitely loops over `foo<Person,Alice>`/`foo<Alice,Person>` when I would like it to use `foo(Person,Person)`. This implementation also allows nonsense like `foo(int,int)` without a compiler-error.

I have been trying to use concepts to require `foo(A,B)` to exist for `foo<B,A>` to be created, but was unable to force exact type-matches for the arguments to `foo`, so `foo(Person,Person)` got overused.

Comment: You can certainly use concepts to constrain the templated `foo`'s parameters to `Person` and its descendants. But in the last case, the templated `foo()` is a better match than `foo(Person,Person)`, which is why you get into a recursive loop. You will have to cast both parameters to `Person` to call `foo(Person,Person)`. You can use `if constexpr` or SFINAE to decide when to do that casting.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to create a concept that simply *invokes* `foo` is unsuccessful because that invocation would always find `foo(Person,Person)`. What was needed was to force the template to accept only EXACT matches to the parameters:

```cpp
template<typename A, typename B>
using foo_func = int(*)(const A&, const B&);

template<typename A, typename B>
concept has_foo = requires
{
  { static_cast<foo_func<A,B>>(&foo) };
};

template<typename A, typename B>
requires has_foo<B, A>
int foo(const A& a, const B& b)
{
  return transpose(foo(b, a));
}
```

This works by using a function-pointer of type `int(*)(A,B)` in the concept. Unlike an invocation, a function-pointer must match all argument-types exactly or it is a different, unrelated function-pointer. The `static_cast` only succeeds if the exact function requested exists among the available overloads.

The result is that `foo<A,B>` only exists if `foo(B,A)` exists.